# How can I use client_credentials to access another oauth2 resource from a resource server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I want to use client_credentials to access another oauth2-protected resource from a reactive resource-server. The part where I'm accessing the resource server using an issued token is working, but not calling the other resource using webclient.

Using UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository I get `serverWebExchange must be null`, and using AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository I get `principalName must be null`.

Using https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2 works as long as I call the client as a `CommandLineRunner`. None of the other suggestions I have found here on stackoverflow has worked.

What am I missing here? I am using Spring Security 5.2.0 and Spring Boot 2.2.0.

ClientConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class ClientSecurityConfig {

    // UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository version

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());

        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider(CustomClientConfig clientConfig) {
        return ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials(clientCredentialsGrantBuilder ->
                                clientCredentialsGrantBuilder.accessTokenResponseClient(new CustomClient(clientConfig))) // Used to send extra parameters to adfs server
                        .build();
    }


    // AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository version

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }
}

    @Bean
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository, CustomClientConfig clientConfig) {

        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials(clientCredentialsGrantBuilder ->
                                clientCredentialsGrantBuilder.accessTokenResponseClient(new CustomClient(clientConfig))) // Used to send extra parameters to adfs server
                        .build();
        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfig:

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class ResourceServerConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/actuators/**", "/api/v1").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .oauth2Client(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
    @RestController()
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1")
    static class Ctrl {
        final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ctrl.class);
        final WebClient webClient;

        public Ctrl(WebClient webClient) {
            this.webClient = webClient;
        }

        @RequestMapping("protected")
        Mono<JsonNode> protected(@RequestParam String data) {
            return webClient.post()
                    .uri("https://other-oauth2-protected-resource")
                    .attributes(clientRegistrationId("myclient"))
                    .bodyValue("{\"data\": \"" + data + "\"}")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
        }
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://adfsserver.com/adfs/services/trust
          jwk-set-uri: https://adfsserver.com/adfs/discovery/keys
      client:
        registration:
          myclient:
            provider: adfs
            client-id: <client-id>
            client-secret: <client-secret>
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            scope: read
        provider:
          adfs:
            token-uri: https://adfsserver.com/adfs/oauth2/token
            jwk-set-uri: https://adfsserver.com/adfs/discovery/keys
```

Comment: Seems like there is missing a reactive counterpart for AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager; see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7544

Comment: Please check my answer (although I know it's really late). Would appreciate if you please accept and close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has recently been fixed by the Spring Project Contributors as part of this [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/7702) but unfortunately the official Spring doc is not yet updated.

The normal servlet approach doc is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-authorized-manager-provider)
If you prefer to choose the "reactive" approach, then configuring a webclient requires only two beans:

1. the AuthorizedClientManager Bean, and
2. the webClient Bean

```
  @Bean
  public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
      ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
      ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
            .clientCredentials()
            .build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
        new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
  }


  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
  }
```

You can refer to my [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/abhi2495/51ad47394da2effc0fb63f97b3a78e37) which has all the required configuration.